# strange css display: flex stops only works on class, not tag

Tags: html, css

Briefly, I have a `header` tag that only has `display: flex` applied to it when I refer to it by class, not the tag itself.

I have the following html:

```
<header class="flexBox">
    <h1 class="title">T</h1>
</header>
```

And the following css

```
.flexBox {   
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: red;
   height: 20em;
}
h1{
    color: blue;
}
```

Which works. The title is centered exactly in the middle of the header. However, if I change the css just a bit so that the css is applied to `header` and not `.flexBox` the flex behavior stops working. Even though in this example `header` and `.flexBox` apply to the same element That is...

```
header {
    display: flex;
    ...
}
```

...will drop the flex behavior, though all other css still works--background color and so on.

To make sure I wasn't missing something obvious, I removed all other css except what is listed. Problem exists across Firefox and Chrome.

I tried making a jsFiddle, but the jsFiddle applies the flex to `header` as well as `.flexBox`, which is the expected behavior.

EDIT: I was missing a curly bracket. Issue remains the same.

Comment: Chances are there is some other CSS overriding that `display` property somewhere.

Comment: It should work. Unless you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE), your question is off-topic. See: [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your CSS is missing a closing `}`.  Is this just a copy/paste issue?

Comment: That was my thinking, but there _is_ no other css at this point. It's an HTML document with the above structure and the css. Nothing else.

Comment: @crowhill Please include the full code of that document.

Comment: Post a link or something. If we can't reproduce it we won't be able to fix it... You're sure you're not adding some inline css or a normalize stylesheet or something? What do the Dev Tools say? Which `display` rule is being applied to your `header` ?

Comment: It was gulp injecting some "nomalizing" css. So yes, everyone was right. Code does work as written. Is there a way to rescind a question?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me in FF and Chrome

```
header {   
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   background-color: red;
   height: 20em;
}
```

Comment: maybe make sure you aren't doing .header?